# echo PHP code inside if condition PHP

Tags: php, opencart

I want to add PHP into PHP if statement. More precisely I want to show/hide modules in OpenCart according to permission.
I ended up with something like this:

```
<?php if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'module/' <?php echo $extension['name']; ?> ')) { ?>
```

whole implementation

```
<?php foreach ($extensions as $extension) { ?>
      <?php if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'module/' <?php echo $extension['name']; ?> ')) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="left"><?php echo $extension['name']; ?></td>
        <td class="right"><?php foreach ($extension['action'] as $action) { ?>
          [ <a href="<?php echo $action['href']; ?>"><?php echo $action['text']; ?></a> ]
          <?php } ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with just: `$this->user->hasPermission('access', 'module/'.$extension['name'])`?

Comment: And ? What is your problem ? What is your question ?

Comment: You don't have to open and close PHP on each line. You can just write `<?php foreach (...) { if (condidition) { ... ` You only need to close them if you want to start raw (html) output.

Comment: @Naruko17, This is an opencart specific question. Try http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a mistake. it should be like:

```
user->hasPermission('access', 'module/'.$extension['name'])) { ?>
```

Comment: For completeness: You needed [string concatination](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: I tried this before, but my output was always nothing, than I realized that the .$extension['name'] starts always with uppercase letter thus the condition was never met and that was causing the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`<?php if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'module/' <?php echo $extension['name']; ?> ')) { ?>`

This won't work. You are already in PHP so attempting to do that other echo within will just result in a syntax error. You are looking to concatenate string here:

```
<?php if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'module/' . $extension['name'] )) { ?>
```

see docs:http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

Code is messy and error prone, I suggest you to do it all in PHP.

Echo the HTML and user proper string concatenation.

```
<?php
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'module/'.$extension['name'])) {
        echo '<tr>
        <td class="left">'.$extension['name'].'</td>
        <td class="right">';
        foreach ($extension['action'] as $action) { 
           echo '[ <a href="'.$action['href'].'">'.$action['text'].'</a> ]';
        }
          echo '</td>'; 
        echo'</tr>';
    } 
}
```